# Usage of local-time's make-timestamp macro

Tags: date, macros, common-lisp

I'm a beginner with Common Lisp and I'm currently trying out the package [local-time](http://common-lisp.net/project/local-time/).

I'm trying to create a date with the `make-timestamp` macro which creates an instance of `timestamp`. I consulted the [local-time manual](http://common-lisp.net/project/local-time/manual.html), but I do not understand which arguments I have to supply.

The description of the macro is as follows:

> — Macro: make-timestamp &key :day :sec :nsec
>
> Expands to an expression that creates an instance of a timestamp exactly as specified.

Simply using the macro without any arguments makes this happen:

```
LOCAL-TIME> (make-timestamp)
@2000-03-01T01:00:00.000000+01:00
```

2000-03-01 is the standard epoch here, so this seems okay so far.

Passing `:day 3` as an argument gives me this:

```
LOCAL-TIME> (make-timestamp :day 3)
@2000-03-04T01:00:00.000000+01:00
```

Okay. But how can I construct a date from this without having to count days and days into the future from 2000-03-01?

There is also a function called `encode-timestamp` which appears to do exactly what I want (namely: creating a date by supplying information like the day of the month, month, year, hour, minutes and so on):

```
LOCAL-TIME> (encode-timestamp 0 0 30 10 13 5 2009)
@2009-05-13T10:30:00.000000+02:00
```

But then, what is the `make-timestamp` macro supposed to do?

Comment: `#'make-timestamp` makes no sense. `#'` is a prefix for functions. The macro is called just `make-timestamp`.

Comment: `make-timestamp` is just syntactic sugar over `(make-instance 'timestamp ...`.

Comment: Specifically, `#'make-timestamp` is `(function make-timestamp)`, and " it is an error to use function on a symbol that denotes a macro or special form." See http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_fn.htm

Comment: @RainerJoswig Given what it expands to, and the fact that it looks like a function, I wonder why it's defined as a macro rather than a function (or a function and an associated compiler macro).

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor : usually for those implementations which don't support explicit inlining in all cases. There are those...

Comment: @RainerJoswig I suppose… It just seems that, like Múna did, it's very tempting to treat something called `make-timestamp` as a function (e.g., `#'make-timestamp`) since in _use_, it rather acts like one.

Comment: I'm very sorry for having caused a confusion. My only intention was to be as specific as possible, and (if I'm not completely mistaken) since `#'` is like saying "the function itself" (as opposed to "a call to the function"), I thought it would be a good idea to write it this way. I didn't know that it makes a difference whether I'm talking about functions or about macros, but that's probably because I still have a lot to learn about macros and about Common Lisp in general. So, thank you for your advice :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Make-timestamp` is used by several of the encoding functions, including `encode-timestamp`.  I would regard it as rather lowlevel, but it might be of interest to a user of the library.

`Encode-timestamp` seems to be just the function you want.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will go with `encode-timestamp` then.